# Как сделать новости на сайте?

Tags: php, html

На сайте необходимо сделать новостную ленту, пробовал новостную ленту от яндекса, он не подходит, так как нет возможности отображения изображений. Может есть альтернатива, которая будет  функциональней?

Answer (score 3):

Если вам надо свою новостную ленту внедрить на свой сайт, то для этого проделайте следующие шаги:

1. Создайте таблицу вида примерно как этого: Название news Поля: ID, TitleNew, PreviewText, TextNew, DateNew, PictureNew, OtherInfo.
2. Создайте в каком-либо месте сайта раздел новостей, обрамленный в div и содержащий картинку, заголовок, дата статьи и контекстную часть превьюшки, а также ссылку на подробное описание новости. Еще нужно создать страницу подробного описания новости, где будет заголовок, картинка, текст новости, дата.
3. В коде через цикл обрабатываем все записи новостей и выводим их в блоке листа новостей, примерно так:

   ```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY DateNew DESC";
           $result = $conn->query($sql);
           if ($result->num_rows)
           {
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
              { ?> 
              <div id="post">
               <div style="border:#AFEEEE solid 1px;padding:10px">
                <h1><a href="details.php?id_new=<?=$row[ID]?>" style="text-align: left;"><?=$row['TitleNew']?></a></h1>
               <img src="<?=$row['PictureNew']?>" width="220" class="leftimg">
               <a href="details.php?id_new=<?=$row[ID]?>">Читать новость полностью >></a> 
           </div>
          </div><br/>
        <?php 
         }
        }
   ```

Писал на коленках, потому могут быть ошибки. Вообщем успехов Вам в работе.